# How can I make a non-contextual parser in ocaml using purely functional programming?

Tags: parsing, functional-programming, ocaml

I am trying to create a non-contextual parser using purely functional programming in OCaml. The function will take a string list and return true if it follows the format of (a^x b^y c^z d^k), meaning that the list needs to contain any number (greater than 0) of "a", "b", "c", and "d".

It was recommended to me that I try to create a set of mutually recursive functions but I have struggled to figure out a way to do that successfully.

Here are some example inputs and outputs of the function:

```
# string(["a";"b";"c";"d"]);;
- : bool = true

# string(["a";"a";"b";"c";"c";"c";"d"]);;
- : bool = true

# string(["a";"c";"d";"d"]);;
- : bool = false
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like matching the regular language `a+b+c+d+`?

Comment: @DanD. Exactly. The string list needs to match the regular expression a+b+c+d+ using purely functional programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to making something purely functional is that all the state has to be passed as function parameters and return values. In your case the state is the input stream; i.e., the list that hasn't been parsed yet.

One way to do this is to have each parsing function return a boolean saying whether it saw what was expected, and also return the unparsed remainder of the list.

This means you would use parsing functions with a type like this:

```
aplus : string list -> bool * string list
bplus : string list -> bool * string list
```

If you were just looking for a's followed by b's you could code it up like this:

```
let parse strings =
    let (good, rest) = aplus strings in
    if not good then false
    else let (good, rest) = bplus rest in
    good && rest = []
```

This is pretty cumbersome code. It might be tidier if you had a function that works like "&&" except that it passes the unparsed list along to the next function. This kind of thing comes up frequently when you start to write purely functional code.

There would be many other ways to structure the parsing, some probably much better than the above. But the key (IMHO) is that your parse functions need to return the remainder of the input stream as well as a success/fail indication.

(Note that there's no recursion here yet, but that will come when you write the individual parsing functions.)